# How to restore multiple keypairs from a mnemonic phrase using python?

Tags: wallet, keypair

```
solana-keygen recover 'prompt:?key=0/0'
```

```
const mnemonic =
  "neither lonely flavor argue grass remind eye tag avocado spot unusual intact";
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic, ""); // (mnemonic, password)
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const path = `m/44'/501'/${i}'/0'`;
  const keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(derivePath(path, seed.toString("hex")).key);
  console.log(`${path} => ${keypair.publicKey.toBase58()}`);
}
```

CLI command and typescript code is available in [solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase) to do this however I need python code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [`bip-utils`](https://pypi.org/project/bip-utils/) module is what you want.  It supports both BIP39 mnemonics and BIP32-ed25519 (SLIP0010) keypair derivation.  There's even a [Solana example](https://github.com/ebellocchia/bip_utils/blob/master/examples/bip32_ed25519_slip.py)

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED:**
[solanapy](https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/) is a great Python library for working with Solana that emulates much of Solana's `web3.js` - however they don't include a way to derive keys from seed phrases.

For that, you'll need `bip_utils` as @trent.sol mentioned.

Taking the Solana example in his answer, you can use the two (if you wanted to) by tacking this on to the end of the example code:

```
from solana.keypair import Keypair


... (code from example Trent linked) ...


keypair = Keypair.from_seed(bip32_der_ctx.PrivateKey().KeyObject().Raw().ToBytes())
```

Comment: This module appears to support neither BIP39 mnemonics, nor BIP32-ed25519 keypair derivation.

Comment: Edited to include `bip_utils`

Comment: pretty sure it's still inaccurate (or that python lib is using bad names).  the private key isn't the same as the seed, it is derived from it.  the data dependencies are, `seed -> private key -> public key`