# How to create Keypair from Phatom private key string with Solana.py?

Tags: python

[image]

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey

client: Client = Client('https://api.devnet.solana.com')
private_key = 'stringFromPhatom'
sender = Keypair.from_secret_key(private_key)
print(sender.public_key)
```

I had this code but I don't know how to convert that string into the bytes needed in Keypair.from_secret_key() to work.

I tried b'private_key' and base64.b64encode(b'private_key') but it's another wallet because when I print it's not the same public key I have on Phantom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore multiple keypairs from a mnemonic phrase using python?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-to-restore-multiple-keypairs-from-a-mnemonic-phrase-using-python)

Comment: No. I am not using the recovery phrase but in Phantom you can export private key and its somethig like 'WAjdsw2lnD2jdn2380nd1ljdwenel'

Comment: ah sorry, misread. sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be base58, not base64

EDIT:

Ok so this library is pretty wreckless with it's use of `seed` and `secret_key`.  While it ends up doing the right thing in the end, the docs and source are confusing if you know what those terms actually mean.

This should work

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import base58
>>> from solana.keypair import Keypair
>>> exported='4UhnbpVAaXHYiQ1Sh85cGjo9WpULGh9RN5V84wnQqipoQvLHkhQWyB7gXKzuhQFSwC4uoibUvD4qRwX1k8doAZyz'
>>> bytes=base58.b58decode(exported)
>>> secret_key=bytes[:32]
>>> keypair=Keypair.from_secret_key(secret_key)
>>> print(keypair.public_key)
GAJ4qgpFtMsYJ5Dw6VDPUYGqkhbrr7o7fECYANYAkzqe
```

Comment: Will try with base58

Comment: So I tried:

base58.b58encode(private_key) and still is not printing the right Public Key

Comment: yeah it looks like this python library is totally wrong (or at least using very wrong terminology).  gimme a few

Comment: ok edited my answer

Comment: Great! This worked!